# how to lauch an 3rd application automatically when the android phone is switched on

Tags: android

can any one tell me "how to lauch an 3rd application automatically when the android phone is switched on?". As I want to launch an application which is written by me when the device is turned on.
I will be waiting for any valuable reply .

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You shouldn't do this. There's enough going on at boot time that you shouldn't be launching applications. Unless the user specifically requests it, you're just going to make them uninstall your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need an implementation of [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which is intended on `BOOT_COMPLETED` action. Like this:

```
public class OnStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
     // but it is better here to do that:
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
     context.startActivity(myIntent);
  }

}
```

Also, you should add [`receiver`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) tag to your manifest file with `android:name` = your fully qualified name of OnStartReceiver and intent-filter tag nested with [`BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) as intent name, like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".onStartReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                    
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver >
```

Comment: Pretty sure it has to be registered to a broadcast receiver, not an activity.

Comment: lacks an experiment, may be perform it tonight.

Comment: `BOOT_COMPLETED` absolutely only works with `BroadcastReceiver`.