# use Alarm Manager to set alarm in Android

Tags: android

In my Android application I would like to set alarm at a particular time with some message for time entered by user.

How can I set alarm using broadcast receiver? Is it possible to pop up a message on the specified time other than the default message?

Answer (score 2):

```
AlarmManager alr =  (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("YourAction");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0/** som unique id*/, intent, 0);
alr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0/** here is a delay*/, pendingIntent);
```

after that you should create a `BroadcastReceiver`, that will get intent with `action = "YourAction"`. From that receiver you can start an activity which will shoiw you the dialog with your custom messages. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450347/how-to-lauch-an-3rd-application-automatically-when-the-android-phone-is-switched/4450405#4450405) answer to see how to setup the BroadcastReceiver.